# Guessing Game Help :)

Tags: java, boolean, java.util.scanner

Ok, so my computer teacher has asked us to make a simple game that asks the user to guess a radomly generated number, but I want to take it one step further and make it so that it display error messages when the user tries certain things. The problem here is that I am new to booleans and well, I am having a bit of trouble using java.util.Scanner and booleans. So, if anyone could take a quick look at this I would appreciate it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class MoreGuessing{
//Instantiation            
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random number = new Random();
//Variables
    int randomnumber = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
    int cntr = 1;
    static String decimalguessed;
    String error1 = "Error001: Decimal found, please enter a whole number between 1-10." + "\n" + "Program terminated......";//Decimal portion error.
    String error2 = "Please enter a positive number." + "\n" + "Program terminated......"; //Negative number error.
    String error3 = "Unknown character entered." + "\n" + "Program terminated......"; //Unknown character error.
//Verifier
public static boolean verifyLetters() {
    if (decimalguessed.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}        
public static void main(String [] args){
//Input and display
    System.out.print("Please enter a whole number between 1-10: ");
        decimalguessed = reader.nextLine();
//Process and Errors
while (decimalguessed != randomnumber) {
if (verifyLetters() != false){
            System.out.println(error3);
            System.exit(1);}
if (decimalguessed % 1 != 0) {
            System.out.println(error1); 
            System.exit(1);}
if (decimalguessed < 0) {
            System.out.println(error2); 
            System.exit(1);}
if (randomnumber != decimalguessed){
            System.out.println("You've lost, please make another attempt.");}
System.out.print("Please enter a whole number between 1-10: ");
    decimalguessed = reader.nextDouble();

cntr++;

    }
if (cntr == 1) {System.out.println("Congratulations! You've guessed the number on your first attempt!");;
}
else {System.out.println("Congratulations! You've guessed the number, it took you " + cntr + " tries");}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse your input. `decimalguessed` is a string, and so you can't do comparisons like `decimalguessed % 1`.

You can convert it to an integer like this:

```
int guess = 0;
try {
    guess = Integer.parseInt(decimalguessed);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Your guess was not an integer: " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
```

This will handle both cases where `decimalguessed` contains letters, and where it contains decimal points/fractions. `decimalguessed` is still a string, but `guess` now contains the integer version of it, so you can compare it to `randomnumber` properly. (Your loop would have never exited before, because a string is never == an integer)

---

Some other notes:

You should never have:

```
if (condition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

This can always be simply replaced with

```
return condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you're very new to this. Welcome to programming!

So first, in Java generally you're not going to have all of that instantiation and variables stuff outside of your main function, unless you're going to make everything static. I would move all of that into your main function, un-static the decimalguessed variable and setup your verifyLetters function to take an argument of String decimalguessed. It may also be wise to check if the value is a number, rather than seeing if it is not a letter. There a lot of non-number, non-letter characters.

Once you've figured out that the guess is a number, you need to tell java it is one (cast it) to a decimal, then do you further comparisons against that decimal.

Darth Android also makes some good points, especially about booleans. You should never have the only result of an if/else be to return a boolean, just return the boolean. Also avoid comparisons to true/false, just do the if on the function/variable alone, or negate it with an '!' to check for false.

Good luck!